# .NET Forms Authentication logging out users before timeout

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have tried damn near everything I can but users are still being logged out after a very short amount of time. Below I've included my authentication controller and my web.config. This is about the 30th iteration of my auth controller. I've also tried building my own cookies to no avail.

```
//Authentication Controller

public ActionResult Index(Login login)
    {

        if(true)//if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (InVisionTicketContext data = new InVisionTicketContext())
            {

                if (data.Logins.Count(l => l.Email == login.Email) >= 1)
                {
                       var Login = data.Logins.Where(l => l.Deleted == false).SingleOrDefault(l => l.Email.ToLower() == login.Email.ToLower());
                        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Login.Password))
                       {
                           ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
                           return View();
                       }


                    if (PasswordHash.ValidatePassword(login.Password, Login.Password))
                    {

                           FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login.Email, true);

                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
        return View();
    }
```

-

```
//Web.Config
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Authentication"  timeout="28800" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" name="InvTicketCookie"/>
</authentication>
<sessionState timeout="28800" >
</sessionState>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to set a static machineKey in web.config and see if that solves the problem.   If your app pool is restarting regularly for some reason, and the autogenerated key can't be persisted, then you'll get this behavior because ASP.Net won't be able to decrypt the ticket with a new key.

You can see an example of a statically generated machine key [here](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey).

Comment: Would there be a good way to log app pool reboots to see if that's the problem? Have you heard of this being a problem with services like GoDaddy?

Comment: Sure, you should be able to see them in the Windows event log, but you could also log them programmatically on Application_Start.  It's also worth noting that you have multiple web servers, you need a static machine key or you'd get similar behavior as requests from a user are served by web servers other than the one on which their auth ticket was created.

Comment: As to GoDaddy, if you have a shared web hosting plan, I wouldn't be at all surprised if this was the cause, however, that's due to the nature of shared web hosting in general, not GoDaddy specifically.

Comment: This resolved everything, godaddy must be restarting the app pool constantly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating two cookies, one with SetAuthCookie and second with RedirectFromLoginPage. The forms authentication module gets confused and sliding expires only one of these cookies. Unfortunately the second one, which expires sooner or later, log users out.

Either remove SetAuthCookie or if you leave it, redirect manually with Response.Redirect.

Comment: The redirectFromLogin is new, I just tried that today so it still won't function properly without it.

Comment: That's unfortunate and you should edit your question to reflect that.